# Having trouble inserting new objects into an embedded array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to Mongodb and I've been having hell of a time trying to get embedded array working. On insert, I'm able to insert the first element of the array without a problem. However when I update, it keeps throwing an error that '0 is not an Object', which is vague for a error message. What can I do to fix it?

Here are my schema:

```
FightCards.schema = new SimpleSchema({
    event_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    player_id: {
        type: String
    },
    fighters: {
        type: [Object]
    },
    'fighters.$.id': {
        type: Number
    },
    'fighters.$.name': {
        type: String
    },
    'fighters.$.salary': {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

Here is the offending code:

```
 if(FightCards.find({}).count() == 0) {
            FightCards.insert(
                {event_id: this.props.event_id, player_id: Meteor.userId(), fighters: [ {id: fighter.id, name: fighter.first_name + " " + fighter.last_name, salary: salary} ]}, 
                (err, res) => {
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                }
            );
} else {
            FightCards.update({event_id: this.props.event_id, player_id: Meteor.userId()},
                { $push: { fighters: [{id: fighter.id, name: fighter.first_name + " " + fighter.last_name, salary: salary}]}},
                (err, res) => {
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                }
            );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to push an array onto an array, you only need to push the element. Change:

```
{ $push: { fighters: [{ id: fighter.id, name: fighter.first_name + " " +
  fighter.last_name, salary: salary }]}},
```

to

```
{ $push: { fighters: { id: fighter.id, name: fighter.first_name + " " +
  fighter.last_name, salary: salary }}},
```

Also you can simplify your code by setting up the query once since `$push` will create the array if it doesn't yet exist:

```
let query = {
  event_id: this.props.event_id,
  player_id: Meteor.userId()},
  { $push: { fighters: {
    id: fighter.id,
    name: fighter.first_name + " " + fighter.last_name,
    salary: salary
  }}
};

if( FightCards.find({}).count() ) {
  FightCards.update(query,(err, res) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
  });
} else {
  FightCards.insert(query,(err, res) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that fixed it.